# How to Build Xcode build with Maven plugin

Tags: xcode, maven, sup, sap-smp

I'm trying to build Xcode app with maven plugin, I wrote `pom.xml` as shown in below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <groupId>com.yqlabsEnterprise.SampleMaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>SampleMaven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>xcode-lib</packaging>
 
    <build>
     <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
             <groupId>com.sap.prd.mobile.ios.mios</groupId>
             <artifactId>xcode-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>1.14.0</version>
             <extensions>true</extensions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
     </build>
</project>
```

I installed maven, and run with maven using terminal, but my app not build successfully, I got error:

> Failed to execute goal com.sap.prd.mobile.ios.mios:xcode-maven-plugin:1.14.0:prepare-xcode-build (default-prepare-xcode-build) on project SampleMaven: Execution default-prepare-xcode-build of goal com.sap.prd.mobile.ios.mios:xcode-maven-plugin:1.14.0:prepare-xcode-build failed: A required class was missing while executing com.sap.prd.mobile.ios.mios:xcode-maven-plugin:1.14.0:prepare-xcode-build: Lorg/sonatype/aether/RepositorySystem

Will you please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you fixed this issue by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to downgrade to Maven 3.0.x since [the plugin is not compatible with later versions of Maven](https://github.com/sap-production/xcode-maven-plugin/issues/131). The reason is that the Java package  `org.sonatype.aether.*` has been renamed to `org.eclipse.aether.*`.